# Stored Procedure Data Not being Populated in Table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE TempTable (
[Fiscal Quarter] varchar(50),
[Unique ID] int,
[Forecasted Amount (converted)] Numeric (25,2),
[Lead Source] varchar(50),
[AD] varchar(50),
[Stage] varchar(50),
[Opportunity Name] varchar(50))


INSERT INTO TempTable Exec [MOPs].[MSP_INQTRWon_Final_Proc_VG]
```

**
Question: When I insert data from stored procedure into a table; it shows 0 rows affected. However when I execute the stored procedure it says 455 rows affected.
**

Comment: It may help people to answer your question if you post the code of your stored procedure. Your "question" is kind of like saying: "I have a black box. When I hit it on the top, it does nothing but when I shake it from side to side, it makes a buzzing sound." If I don't know what's in the black box, I can't tell you why it behaves like that.

Comment: That's not mysql code - please amend tags

Answer (score 0):

> However when I execute the stored procedure it says 455 rows affected.

When you execute the stored procedure it should return rows like select statement in order to insert those rows into a table. Instead if it's just doing some operation on those rows there is nothing to insert.

Please confirm whether your stored procedure returns rows when you execute.

In MySQL stored procedure is executed via `call procedurename();`
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/call.html

SQLServer use `exec`. Is your database MySQL? Then which version?